# How delete post_content records of specific category from phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, post-content

I need a SQL command to delete post_content records for specific category's posts

Comment: post_content is a column on the wp_posts table, not a record in itself. Do you mean you want to delete all posts with a specific category?

Comment: Can you show us how far you've got on your own, your best attempt so far? That might make it clearer what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Rup I just want to delete content of posts not the main post. I mean the posts won't have contents.